# Qt not refreshing Makefiles after changes in the .pro file

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator, qmake

I'm finding a strange issue with Qt Creator 3.0.1 that is not refreshing the current state of the configuration before compiling and linking. To explain myself better, say my code isn't initially compiling because it's missing a library (e.g. opencv_core248d). If I add it in the .pro file like this:

```
LIBS += -L$$(OPENCV_DIR)/build/x86/vc11/lib -lopencv_core248d
```

the project won't compile and link until I go and manually delete the makefiles generated by qmake (Clean All doesn't work!). After this it will compile, but if I comment the line above it will continue compiling until I manually delete the makefiles again!.

I'm using msvc2012 x86 Qt 5.2.1 and the Qt creator that comes with it. OS is Win7 SP1 x64. Is this a bug on Qt Creator or am I missing something?

Comment: All that you need to do is to re-run qmake. There's no need to clean the project. Right-click on the project's root in project tree and select "Run qmake". Inspect the Makefile to see if there's an action there that makes the Makefile itself dependent on the project file. If there's no such action, then perhaps it's not supported by the build tool (nmake/jom in your case). My guess would be that jom tries to be bug-compatible with nmake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue that sometimes QtCreator does not rerun qmake and you need to rerun qmake explicitly. There is an option in QtCreator to run qmake. There is no need to delete anything in the background, however.

This is a long standing issue still not fixed and it was one of the first reported issues:

[Creator should know when to rerun qmake](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-231)

Comment: IIRC, QtCreator only ever runs qmake if the makefile doesn't exist. The makefile should have an action to re-generate itself when the .pro file has changed. Unfortunately, either qmake doesn't generate the proper actions on some platforms, or the make tool on some platforms doesn't support this properly. I don't remember which is the case, and on what platforms...

Comment: @KubaOber: AFAIK, qmake generates such a target on the supported development host platforms. For making sure, I would need to check the qmake source code, however.