# Why every time I modify the .pro file in Qt I have to run again qmake?

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, compilation, qmake

Why I have to run qmake every time I update my .pro file? Sometimes I see Qt doing it automatically but when I compile I have compilations errors and I have to run manually qmake.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt not refreshing Makefiles after changes in the .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026868/qt-not-refreshing-makefiles-after-changes-in-the-pro-file)

Comment: ***Sometimes I see Qt doing it automatically*** Do you mean `Qt-Creator`? The `Qt` tag is for the framework not the IDE.